# Debug Azure web role integrated with ACS from Android emulator web application

Tags: android, iis-7, azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to access a web role integrated with ACS from the Android emulator , the issue is that 
during web role debug configuration , the ACS redirects back to "localhost" and not to a real URL.
Android emulator local computer localhost address is defined as 10.0.0.2 so when ACS redirects to localhost the emulator web browser fails to redirect.
I tried to let ACS redirect to 10.0.0.2 - but for some unknown reason it doesnt work.

SO! .... after few hours (50) I tried to use IIS 7 as a reverse proxy using Application Request Routing and to make the Android calls directly to my computers LAN ip address and let IIS to redirect the calls to the Azure local host web role :
So , the emulator calls 10.0.0.3:8081 and IIS7 will redirect it to localhost:8082 (which is the web role).

AND! .... after another few hours (280) , I am still investing so much IT time and cant check my web role.

So , now I am here , and hope that someone with expirence in those subjects can help me out .

Azure btw for those of you who do not know , can not be configured locally to publish itself on the local network and can only operate in localhost mode.

Thank you very much .

Ishai

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved , instead of IIS 7 Application Requet Routing I have used Fiddler 2 Reverse proxy option to forward requests to my localhost web role.
Fiddler 2 is configured to publish itself in the LAN at localComputerIp:8888 - e.g. 10.0.0.3:8888 , so then from Android instead of trying to access 10.0.0.2 (localhost) : 8087 - my Azure web role direct address , I set it to connect to Fiddler direct LAN ip at 10.0.0.3:8888 and Fiddler forwarded the requests to localhost:8087.

This took me alot of time to accomplish and even though it might be simple if you have the right knowledge I hope other users will find this post helpful .